# Reverse for '<QuerySet [<ShortURL: https://google.com>]>' not found

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a url shortener and I'm creating the redirect part of it. I have a view that triggers when a user searches the short url that they generated.

```py
# views.py
def page_redirect(request, url):
    get_url = ShortURL.objects.filter(short_url=url)[:1]
    return redirect(get_url)
```

get_url returns `<QuerySet [<ShortURL: https://google.com>]>`. Does anyone know how I would filter `https://google.com` so I can put that url into redirect() to redirect the user to the original long url?

Other Code:

```py
# models.py
class ShortURL(models.Model):
    long_url = models.URLField(max_length=700)
    short_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time_date_created = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.long_url

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:url>', page_redirect, name='redirect'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#first),

```
return redirect(get_url.first().long_url)
```

Or you can index the queryset

```
return redirect(get_url[0].long_url)
```